# Starting Rust Server With c#

Tags: c#

I am experiencing some very odd results when trying to start a Rust server with c#

```
//Top Of Program//
public static StreamWriter WriteCommands;
BackgroundWorker StartServer = new BackgroundWorker();
Process Rust = new Process();
public static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
//////////////////

//Start Button Function//
Rust.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.StartupPath + "servers\\RustServer\\";
Rust.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Rust.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Rust.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Rust.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
Rust.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Rust.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Rust.OutputDataReceived += MainWindow._MainWindow.Rust_OutputDataReceived;
Rust.ErrorDataReceived += MainWindow._MainWindow.Rust_OutputErrorReceived;
Rust.Start();
Rust.BeginOutputReadLine();
Rust.BeginErrorReadLine();
WriteCommands = Rust.StandardInput;
WriteCommands.WriteLineAsync("RusteoServerLauncher.bat");
stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();
/////////////////////////
```

This is the batch file I call from code

```
@echo off
RustDedicated.exe -batchmode +server.hostname "Black Clocks" +server.identity "Black Clocks" +server.level "Procedural Map" +server.seed 27341 +rcon.ip 0.0.0.0 +rcon.port 28016 +rcon.password <password> +server.maxplayers 150 +server.ip 192.168.2.102 +server.port 28015 +server.secure false +server.encryption 0 -cfg "server\IDENTIFICACION\cfg\server.cfg"
```

I am getting only this in the output textbox:

```
D:\Bot\servers\RustServer>RusteoServerLauncher.bat
Mono path[0] = 'D:/Bot/servers/RustServer/RustDedicated_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'D:/Bot/servers/RustServer/RustDedicated_Data/Mono/etc'
Player data archive not found at `D:/Bot/servers/RustServer/RustDedicated_Data/data.unity3d`, using local filesystem
```

But if I set Rust.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow to false. The window that appears is giving me the output I want (The rust server console).

Any Ideas?

EDIT: I kept messing around and found that it seems to be opening another Console Window which is actually giving the servers output. I am not sure how to get the output from that window, hopefully that will make this question easier to answer.

Comment: I have edited your question to put the actual code in the question rather than a link to the code.  In general you should always put the code directly in the question (with a minor edit on the "password" from the batch file)

Comment: sorry, ill keep that in mind, thank you for editing it for me.